# search suggestions and recommendation diffrence

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, search

Whats the difference between search suggestion and search recommendation in Magento. If the Ajax request in search bar is search suggestion, then what is search recommendation. whats the purpose of 'Enable Search Recommendations' in Admin panel. Can we disable search suggestions (Ajax request).

Answer (score 0):

I found it on the internet:

- Enable Search Suggestions: enable so that in case of misspellings a related word was suggested.
- Enable Search Recommendations – set up at Yes so that the system will put out recommendations in case the returns no match.

To refer: https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-set-up-magento-search.html